# Hibernate. Lazy-load. Best practice. What wrong?

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-initialization

I'm writing a test server on Spring and Hibernate.

During the execution of the code, I received an LazyInitializationException.

I found two bad solutions: Open Session in View and
hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans. I did not use them.

I found a solution that works, but as other people write it's also not very good. Above the entity I put an annotation @Proxy(lazy = false).

Tell me please, what better to change in the project that everything would work CORRECTLY?

Link to the project in [GitHub](https://github.com/RusKryzhanovskiy/MyTweeterServer).

The project is very small and contains only eight small .java and two .properties files.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: If you project is working you will want to move this question to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you're trying to lazy-load some entities outside a hibernate transaction. The best way, in my opinion, to execute code which actually working with entities inside one transaction. You need to configure transaction manager(if it is not yet) and put @Transactional(from hibernate package) on the method.